# TSQL Select Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

Just curious... is there a command in TSQL which will delete rows I just selected from a table?

In pseudo SQL, something like

```
SELECT * FROM TableA THEN DELETE
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WITH (DELETEROWS)
```

NOTE: I'm not just looking to delete rows, I want to return the rows to a temptable and *then* delete them, in the same statement

Comment: `delete from tablea where pk_column in (select pk_column from tablea where ...)`

Comment: You just change `SELECT * ...` to `DELETE ...` and re-execute it.

Comment: I guess OP wants to output and then delete and not just delete.

Comment: @juergend yes, I want to read AND delete the rows in one single operation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the rows that were *just* deleted using the [output clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
DELETE FROM TableA
OUTPUT deleted.* --TODO name columns, identify table to insert into, etc
```

So, overall should be the same, just the order of operations is reversed.

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `OUTPUT` statement in the `DELETE`.  This will allow you to capture all the details of the deleted rows.

If you do the `SELECT` first, you would need to capture those rows into a table, and then delete the rows in the table.

If you repeat the logic for the `SELECT`, you *could* run into problems, because new rows may have been inserted/modified/deleted between the `SELECT` and the `DELETE`, so the two might not be consistent.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Day = '201507015'
```

This will delete all records from table with name Table 1, column Day, where the record in this column is for today - 20150715 (yyyymmdd).